# no route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a file reports/print.html.erb

in reports_controller

```
def print
  @report = Report.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :layout => false }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @report }
  end
end
```

in routes.rb

```
match 'reports/print(:id)'
```

trying to call with

```
<%= link_to 'Print', report_print_path(:id => @report.id), :method => :put %>
```

and getting this error:

ActionController::RoutingError in Reports#show 
No route matches {:action=>"print", :id=>23, :controller=>"report"}

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: when I run $rake routes, I get "missing controller" maybe I have a typo somewhere...

Comment: BTW, this error is on the page that the link is on.

Answer (score 1):

Change your route to:

```
match 'reports/print/:id' => 'controller#print', :via => :put
```

That may fix it (didn't test the code though, and change the `'controller#print'` part to your actual controller name.

Comment: match 'reports/print/:id' => 'reports#print', :via => :put

Answer (score 0):

made it work with

```
<%= link_to 'Print', print_url(:id => @report.id) %>
```

and

```
match 'print/(:id)' => 'reports#print', :via => :get, :as => :print
```

No idea why it was giving me problems, there's 4 hours of my life i'll never get back.